# JSP form returing to 404 instead of mapping to a controller's method

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, controller

I want to map the form action with the controller method as below, but i get the 404 page not found error.

my JSP page:

```
    <h1>Welcome to SportyShoes</h1>
    
    <form action="loginaction" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="adminname">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

my controller page:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginaction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginAction(ModelMap map, @RequestParam(value="adminname") String adminName, @RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
        
        Admin admin = adminService.authenticate(adminName, password);
        if(admin == null) {
            map.addAttribute("error", "admin name or password is wrong");
            return null;
        }
        return "entry";
        
    }
}
```

but i get the error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> JSP file [/WEB-INF/views/loginaction.jsp] not found

my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sportyshoes</groupId>
    <artifactId>sportyshoes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sportyshoes</name>
    <description>An e-commerce for sporty shoes</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--embeded tomcat is to suppor the jsp-->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
     <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency> -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What did I do wrong? Please find my POM which I have included. It was working fine before and I did a few changes and redid the entire files now it is showing this 404 error.

Comment: It looks like your application tries to access the file loginaction.jsp (which doesn't exist) instead of calling your controller's method for `/loginaction`. Can you show us your Tomcat dependencies (e.g. pom.xml if you're using Maven)?

Comment: yes you are right. Please find my updated POM in the question. It was working fine before and I redid the files and now it is not functioning properly. What might be the reason?

Comment: Spring Boot 3 must use Java `17`, not `11`, your pom.xml `<java.version>11</java.version>`

Comment: changed the java version to 17, still showing the same error.

Comment: I think something has happened to the JSP support in Spring Boot 3.  I have an application that worked fine on Spring Boot 2.7 but on 3.0 it does a similar thing.

Comment: Maybe. Anyway thanks for your valuable feedback.